# Tools To Manage Server Through SSH

Tags: 11.10, server, ssh, remote-access

Any Tool Like This In Ubuntu server so i can manage easily my server through SSH

Yast tool open in SSH
[image]

Comment: can you provide more detail on what you are trying to achieve.  Are you coming from openSUSE, or trying more advanced support / maintenance over SSH?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There appears to be work in progress, to try and provide this.

Have you looked at attempts to date?

https://wiki.ubuntu.com/YaST

https://launchpad.net/~yast

https://code.launchpad.net/people/yast/+branch/yast/packaging-trunk

Answer (score 0):

You can use aptitude for update only i use it on ubuntu server 11.10. I don't know if there is a control center that can manage hardware. Does it has to be ssh? you can install [Webmin](http://www.upubuntu.com/2011/09/how-to-install-webmin-on-ubuntu.html) to manage your server.

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing in Debian or Ubuntu that directly compares to YaST. The philosophy on both distributions is to work directly with the configuration files, or use a graphical desktop for things like setting up printers.